# Disable Same Option if Select Under Same Class [with Bootstrap Select]

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, search

I copied some code from here and implemented it on a two sets of code. The goal is to prevent already selected options from being picked on other selectlists if they have the same class. Normally it works (left side picklists) but it doesn't seem to automatically work with [Bootstrap Select with Search](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) (right side picklists) as I noticed it made some new elements.

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">

  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 70px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <h3>no selectpicker class</h3>
            <select class="show-tick form-control noBSselect">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Strength">Strength</option>
                <option value="Agility">Agility</option>
                <option value="Constitution">Constitution</option>
                <option value="Dexterity">Dexterity</option>
                <option value="Charm">Charm</option>
                <option value="Luck">Luck</option>
            </select>
            <select class="show-tick form-control noBSselect">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Strength">Strength</option>
                <option value="Agility">Agility</option>
                <option value="Constitution">Constitution</option>
                <option value="Dexterity">Dexterity</option>
                <option value="Charm">Charm</option>
                <option value="Luck">Luck</option>
            </select>
            <select class="show-tick form-control noBSselect">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Strength">Strength</option>
                <option value="Agility">Agility</option>
                <option value="Constitution">Constitution</option>
                <option value="Dexterity">Dexterity</option>
                <option value="Charm">Charm</option>
                <option value="Luck">Luck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <h3>with selectpicker class</h3>
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control withBSselect" data-live-search="true">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option disabled>sample</option>
                <option value="Strength">Strength</option>
                <option value="Agility">Agility</option>
                <option value="Constitution">Constitution</option>
                <option value="Dexterity">Dexterity</option>
                <option value="Charm">Charm</option>
                <option value="Luck">Luck</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control withBSselect" data-live-search="true">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option disabled>sample</option>
                <option value="Strength">Strength</option>
                <option value="Agility">Agility</option>
                <option value="Constitution">Constitution</option>
                <option value="Dexterity">Dexterity</option>
                <option value="Charm">Charm</option>
                <option value="Luck">Luck</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control withBSselect" data-live-search="true">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option disabled>sample</option>
                <option value="Strength">Strength</option>
                <option value="Agility">Agility</option>
                <option value="Constitution">Constitution</option>
                <option value="Dexterity">Dexterity</option>
                <option value="Charm">Charm</option>
                <option value="Luck">Luck</option>
            </select>
        </div>

      <br/><br/>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //without bs-select
    var $noBSselect = $(".noBSselect");
    $noBSselect.on("change", function() {

        $noBSselect.find("option").prop("disabled", false);

        $noBSselect.each(function() {
           $noBSselect.not(this)
                .find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]')
                .prop("disabled", true); 
        });

    });

    //with bs-select
    var $withBSselect = $(".withBSselect");
    $withBSselect.on("change", function() {

        $withBSselect.find("option").prop("disabled", false);

        $withBSselect.each(function() {
           $withBSselect.not(this)
                   .find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]')
                   .prop("disabled", true); 
        });

    });

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to select different values for each input element? Why do you not validate it with javascript by selected value?